# Word for "a location you are moving away from"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "a location you are moving away from"?

I mean basically the opposite of "destination" or "target", since those mean "a location you are moving toward".

Comment: Origination? Starting point? Port of embarkation?

Comment: Do you mean a location you are *aiming* away from — trying to avoid rather than meet?

Comment: In what context is this word to be used? World travel? The locus of a point on a graph?

Comment: See [Antonym of "target"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571951/antonym-of-target).

Comment: I did see that thread already, and that's certainly related. However that seems to be more "thing you are trying to miss" rather than "origin of your movement".

Comment: @YosefBaskin oo "origin" is a good one. I'd also thought of "starting point" on my own, was hoping there might be one-word answers.

Comment: Wish I knew what the downvotes were for :(  I'd been trying to come up with good answers on my own, finally decided to post here cause I couldn't think of anything better than "starting point" (maybe should have mentioned that in the question).

Comment: If I downvoted, I wouldn't explain. But the question does ask a community to research an antonym of X for you that you may or may not like.

Comment: Isn't that the point (well not antonym, but researching a word for the asker) of every question tagged single-word-requests? My apologies for breaking any rules.

Comment: I didn't DV but did CV because the SWR tag includes specific instructions in capital letters which weren't followed. I'd be happy to remove my CV if the question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

[**Point of departure**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/point-of-departure)

*the precise location of a vessel, established in order to set a course, especially in beginning a voyage in open water*

> e.g. St. Joseph solidified its status as a major **point of departure** for those traveling west with the completion of the Hannibal and St. Joseph Railroad that same year.

[**Jumping-off point**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jumping-off-point#jumping-off-point__1)

*the place where a journey begins*

> e.g. In Sarah Journeys West, Sarah's family's “**jumping off point**” is Kanesville, Iowa. It was renamed Council Bluffs in 1853.